# How do you include a + sign in a filename in paket? It ends up url-encoded

Tags: paket

If you have a paket file with a files section like this:

```
files
    ../bin/profile259/Foo.dll     ==> lib/pq+
```

Then `paket pack` will insert a url-encoded filename lib/pq%2B in the nupkg file that it builds.  What's the right way to specify a filename so the encoding/decoding works correctly?

Paket version 2.62.6.0

---

Resolution: use paket 2.63; this was a bug, not user error.  Fixed in [this patch](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/commit/0d22510d87b48b98b0e5f96849f2adb91c8c2a0e).

Comment: Special characters in filenames are silly. Can't you just rename your file to make it sensible? And are you sure that this isn't expected behaviour? What makes you think that "escaping" the `+` isn't "encoding/decoding work[ing] correctly?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit AFAIK, it's a requirement for directory naming when you want something to be consumed in multiple frameworks, like lib/portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10.  Am I wrong?  (FYI, this turned out to be just a bug and was fixed in https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/commit/0d22510d87b48b98b0e5f96849f2adb91c8c2a0e)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see this shortcoming addressed, you might want to post an issue on GitHub repository contributing detailed reproduce steps or a PR with a failing test:

https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket

Comment: Turns out it was a bug, but when I posted this I thought it was just user error (or just insufficient user training).